# Decoding the molecular formula from high-resolution mass spectrometry

Tags: python

`Your task is to write a Python program that figures out the molecular formula for a
specific mass. For simplicity, we will assume that our molecules contain only four elements C,
H, N, O, the ion observed in the spectrometer has exactly the same mass as the neutral
molecule, and only the most abundant isotopes are present (no pesky carbons-13!). The atomic
masses of those isotopes can be programmed as a Python dictionary:
atoms = {'H': 1.007825, 'C': 12.000000, 'N': 14.003074, 'O': 15.994915}

Your program will read the molecular masses from the masses.txt file (one mass per line). For
each mass, the program will figure out the molecular formula (CxHyNzOw) and print both the
mass and the formula (in the plain-text format without subscripts, CxHyNzOw). If it is not
possible to find a molecular formula for a given mass, the program should print out that there is
no such compound.

I tried

```
# dictionary of masses 
atoms = {'H': 1.007825, 'C': 12.000000, 'N': 14.003074, 'O': 15.994915} 

molecular_formula = ''
target_mass = 16.0313
for atom, mass in atoms.items():
    molecular_formula += atom
    count = target_mass // atoms[atom]  
    if count > 1:
        molecular_formula += str(count)

print(molecular_formula)
```

and got H15.0CNO, I was expecting CH4

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming resulting mass is a combination of masses. If yes, there will be more than one correct answer and you will have to cover every combination before declaring mass combination not found. How you cover all combinations efficiently is a deliberation.

However, below code covers upto two atom combination and you can extrapolate for rest

```py
import decimal

def find_decimals(value):
    return (abs(decimal.Decimal(str(value)).as_tuple().exponent)) 

cmass = 16031300

atoms = {'H': 1007825, 'C': 12000000, 'N': 14003074, 'O': 15994915} 

# only 1 atom
for atom, mass in atoms.items():
    if find_decimals(cmass / mass) == 1:
        print(atom+str(cmass // mass))

# Only 2 atoms
for atom1, mass1 in atoms.items():
    rmass = cmass
    while rmass > mass1:
        rmass = rmass - mass1
        for atom2, mass2 in atoms.items():
            if find_decimals(rmass / mass2) == 1:
                print(atom1+str((cmass-rmass)//mass1)+atom2+str(rmass // mass2))
```

Below is output for above code

```
C1H4
H4C1
```